# How to create an instance of ICLRAppDomainResourceMonitor interface?

Tags: .net, clr

I am trying to create an instance of [ICLRAppDomainResourceMonitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627196.aspx) interface, but I found no clue of what coclass implements it. Without that knowledge, I cannot create an object instance of the coclass and retrieve that interface from the coclass object.

Could anyone help me on this? Many thanks.

Comment: Is this via managed code or...?

Comment: @Aaron, via native code.

Answer (score 2):

In above code we can create instance of ICLRAppDomainResourceMonitor successfully.

Actually I am trying to fetch values of attributes of each AppDomain of each .NET 4.0 processes running on the same system.

I tried following code to fetch data of AppDomain :

```
void getAttributeValues(struct processIDMap *NETProcessID){ //NETProcessID is collection of .NET 4.0 process running on system

    ICorPublishAppDomain* appDomains[1];
    ULONG aFetched = 1;
    
    ICLRMetaHost *meta = NULL;
    ICLRRuntimeInfo *info = NULL;
    ICLRRuntimeHost *host = NULL;
    ICLRControl *control = NULL;
    ICLRAppDomainResourceMonitor *monitor = NULL;


    hr = CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost, IID_ICLRMetaHost, (void **)&meta);
    if (! SUCCEEDED(hr))
        printf("hr failed....");

    
    struct processIDMap *tempStruct = NETProcessID;

    while(tempStruct != NULL ){

        HANDLE pHandle = NULL;
        IEnumUnknown * pRtEnum = NULL;

        DWORD Aid = 0;
        ULONGLONG bytes = 0;
        ULONG fetched = 0;

        pHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION,FALSE,tempStruct->PID);
        hr = meta->EnumerateLoadedRuntimes(pHandle, &pRtEnum);
        if (! SUCCEEDED(hr))
            printf("hr failed....");

        while ((hr = pRtEnum->Next(1,(IUnknown **)&info,&fetched)) == S_OK && fetched > 0){
            
            
            hr = info->GetInterface(CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost, IID_ICLRRuntimeHost, (void **)&host);
            if (! SUCCEEDED(hr))
                printf("hr failed....");
        
            hr = host->GetCLRControl(&control); 
            if (! SUCCEEDED(hr))
                printf("hr failed....");
        
            hr = control->GetCLRManager(IID_ICLRAppDomainResourceMonitor, (void **)&monitor);
            if (! SUCCEEDED(hr))
                printf("hr failed....");

            hr = monitor->GetCurrentAllocated(Aid, &bytes);
            if (! SUCCEEDED(hr))
                printf("hr failed....");

        }

        //info->Release();
        //control->Release();
        //monitor->Release();
        //host->Release();
        
        tempStruct = tempStruct->next;
        pRtEnum->Release();
        CloseHandle(pHandle);
                
    
    }
    
    meta->Release();
```

}

but API  **monitor->GetCurrentAllocated(Aid, &bytes)**   return value of hr as  -2146234348  ie [COR_E_APPDOMAINUNLOADED](https://web.archive.org/web/20151209193307/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eldar/archive/2007/04/03/a-lot-of-hresult-codes.aspx)

Please provide your comments.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a ICLRControl, generated from ICLRRuntimeHost::GetCLRControl, execute ICLRControl::GetCLRManager using IID_ICLRAppDomainResourceMonitor for the desired interface.

e.g.

```
ICLRMetaHost *meta;
ICLRRuntimeInfo *info;
ICLRRuntimeHost *host;
ICLRControl *control;
ICLRAppDomainResourceMonitor *monitor;
CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost, IID_ICLRMetaHost, (void **)&meta);
meta->GetRuntime(L"v4.0.30319", IID_CLRRuntimeInfo, (void **)&runtime);
info->GetInterface(CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost, IID_ICLRRuntimeHost, (void **)&host);
host->GetCLRControl(&control);
control->GetCLRManager(IID_ICLRAppDomainResourceMonitor, (void **)&monitor);

//  ... rest of CLR startup ...

unsigned long long bytes;
monitor->GetCurrentAllocated(1, &bytes);
```

Edit: Note, you have to use the CLR v4.0 for the to work.  Using the 4.0 metahost and 2.0 runtime isn't enough.